# Backbone listener doesn't appear to be firing

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a copule of files that I'm working with and I'm trying to create a listener on this method I have in my backbone view

appView.js.coffee

```
namespace "happiness_kpi", (exports) ->
  exports.appView = Backbone.View.extend

    events: 
      "click #happy" : "selection"

    selection: ->
      console.log "selection was called"
```

index.html.haml

```
%input{ :type => "image", :src => "/assets/smiley.jpg", :alt => "happy", :id => "happy" }
%input{ :type => "image", :src => "/assets/undecided.jpg", :alt => "undecided", :id => "undecided" }
%input{ :type => "image", :src => "/assets/sad.jpg", :alt => "sad", :id => "sad" }
```

and here is my spec: 
app_view_spec.js.coffee

```
it "is called when one of the faces is clicked", ->
  $("body").append('<input alt="happy" id="happy" src="/assets/smiley.jpg" type="image">')
  $("body").append('<input alt="undecided" id="undecided" src="/assets/undecided.jpg" type="image">')
  $("body").append('<input alt="sad" id="sad" src="/assets/sad.jpg" type="image">')
  @subject.selection = sinon.spy()

  $("#happy").click

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(@subject.selection)
```

I'm getting the error 'Error: expected spy to be called once but was called 0 times' Anyone have any ideas as to why the event is not being triggered when the input is clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `click()` with the brackets to trigger the event maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much research and tinkering, I seem to have come to an answer. The problem was definitely the way that I was appending the images to the iframe. Problem was that the test seemed to be creating a new element outside of the iframe, and was not visible to the page. The `$('#happy').click()` was executing correctly, however, it was executing on something that didn't exist in the iframe.

 
**So my solution:**

app_view_spec.js.coffee

```
beforeEach ->
  $("body").append('<div id="display"></div>')

afterEach ->
  $("body").append('<div id ="display"></div>').remove()

it "is called when one of the faces is clicked", ->
  @subject.emotionSelection = sinon.spy()
  @subject.delegateEvents()

  $("input#happy").click()

  sinon.assert.calledOnce @subject.emotionSelection
```

appView.js.coffee
        el: '#display'

```
initialize: ->
  @render()

events: ->
  'click #happy': @emotionSelection

render: ->
  @$el.html HandlebarsTemplates.faces()

emotionSelection: ->
  console.log "hello"
```

I found doing it this way was a much nicer approach, I just appended my HAML to the iframe, rather than trying to append each image on its own. Lesson learned. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is not the obvious typo of the brackets when calling `click()` then the other thing I'm thinking is that the events in Backbone are scoped within the View element. That means that a View cannot list to events happening outside itself (it can, of course, but not by simply using the `events` object).

Try doing this at the beginning of your test:

```
@subject.setElement($("body"));
```

This will set the View `el` and `$el` to the body tag, so the images you are appending are actually going inside your View and the events will be triggered.

Comment: I tried setting `@subject.setElement($("body"));` but I'm getting the error that `el` and `$el` are undefined. I tried to fiddle around with it in the console, but I haven't had much luck there either. I discovered that part of the issue was with my template, but I've resolved that issue, and back to the issue at hand.